# Why are these structurally similar types incompatible?

Tags: typescript

If I declare the following types:

```
export type Type1 = { id: string } | { id: number };
export type Type2 = { id: string } | { id: number };
```

Why do I get an error when used in the following manner:

```
function displayItem(item: Type1) {
  loadItem({ id: item.id });          // error is indicated here
}

function loadItem(item: Type2) {}
```

[image]

My understanding from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html is that they should be equivalent as they are structurally the same.

### **Simpler repro in light of answers (second type is not needed):**

```
export type Type1 = { id: string } | { id: number };

function displayItem(item: Type1) {
   loadItem({ id: item.id });          // error is indicated here
}

function loadItem(item: Type1) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In depth, you are trying to assing a value of type `number | string` to either `number` or a `string`.

Since you are accessing `item.id`, `id` can be `string` or `number`, by your type definition. Your `Type2` expects an object `{id: string}` or `{id: number}` which is different from `{id: string | number}`.

So, two different scenarios could resolve this mishap.

1. Declare your `Type2` to expect one key called `id` which is `number | string`
2. Pass the whole `item` object to your second function. This is the so-called *type compatibility*

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solutions, however I can't do either of them as Type2 is defined in an external library as is the parameter type for the second function. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why not `loadItem(item);`? (Even explicitly `loadItem(item as Type2);`)

Comment: My real world case was more complex than the example, meaning I couldn't use `loadItem(item)` but a variation on your second suggestion works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is not that `Type1` is not equivalent to `Type2`

For example, following will not give an error

```js
function displayItem(item: Type1) {
  loadItem(item);
}

function loadItem(item: Type2) {}
```

The problem arises when you type `item.id` which could be two things. Since `Type1` is defined as `export type Type1 = { id: string } | { id: number };`
the type of this variable could be `string` or `number`. So typescript creates another type for `{id: item.id}` which is `{id: number | string}` as you can see it is not compatible with `Type2`.

You have to explicitly write which type you'd like to use.

Following won't give any error

```js
function displayItem(item: Type1) {
  loadItem({ id: item.id as number});         
}
```

Now, I mark `item.id` as `number` so type of `{ id: item.id as number}` is `{id: number}` which is compatible with `Type2`

Just change your types to following

```js
export type Type1 = { id: string | number};
export type Type2 = { id: string | number};
```

Comment: Good, I missed the point where you can manually force a type. But it should be dependant of the `id` type, not hardcoded. Anyways, good point

Comment: @VRoxa re 'But it should be dependant of the id type, not hardcoded' - is this possible? I don't want to hard code it as it could be either.

Comment: No, as far as I know, you cannot. If you make it dependant, you get a `string | number` type, which is the same what you got before, indeed.

Comment: Just make your type `Type1 = { id: string | number }`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner changing `Type1` gives the same error. Changing `Type2` in the same way eliminates the error, but its an external type I can't modify.